# Compatibility issues for Combinatorica package

Tags: graphs-and-networks, compatibility

I am trying to use the Combinatorica package in a Mathematica version 9 in the following code :

```
graph = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 
    0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}};    
Needs["Combinatorica`"]   
ChromaticNumber[AdjacencyGraph[graph]]
```

The output for this code is

```
ChromaticNumber[<graph>]
```

I think Mathematica does not recognize the function ChromaticNumber. The compatibility guide [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compatibility/tutorial/Combinatorica.html) does not list the function too. How do I use this function ?

Comment: The problem is that `AdjacencyGraph` returns a `Graph` object, which is different from the way graphs are represented in Combinatorica. Try `ChromaticNumber[FromAdjacencyMatrix[graph]]` instead.

Comment: @SimonWoods You are ahead of me by 30 seconds :)

Comment: @ybeltukov, you got my upvote for taking the trouble to write a proper answer :-)

Comment: The IGraph/M package has `IGChromaticNumber`. It's much faster than Combinatorica's implementation and works with built-in `Graph` objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use old-style `Graph` functionality after loading `` Combinatorica` ``

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"];

graph = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 
0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}};

ChromaticNumber[FromAdjacencyMatrix[graph]]
```

> 3

See also:

- [Combinatorica/ref/FromAdjacencyMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/FromAdjacencyMatrix.html)
- [Combinatorica/ref/Graph](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/Graph.html)